# Framework7 Stepper buttons not working

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, html-framework-7

I inserted a stepper into a mobile webapp based on Framework7:

```
        <div class="stepper stepper-init">
          <div class="stepper-button-minus"></div>
          <div class="stepper-input-wrap">
            <input type="text" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly>
          </div>
          <div class="stepper-button-plus"></div>
        </div>
```

However, the two plus/minus buttons for in/decreasing the value do not work...do they need to be initialized? Or am I supposed to write the onclick handlers for these buttons myself?

(Of course, I looked into the Framework7 kitchen sink examples - there I found no indication for manual onclick handling; and the stepper is placed inside a form, and the app is properly initialized and works well, otherwise;-)

Comment: Normally, it's `stepper-init` that make automatically initialization..

Comment: True, but stepper-init is set (see code snippet). Can anything interfere with the initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I worked it out: experimenting with a multipage app, I had my `<div class="page">` wrapped inside a `<div class="pages">` element - and this seems to have interfered with the stepper initialization.

As soon as I removed the `<div class="pages">` (leaving only a single page inside a `<div class="page">`), the stepper buttons worked.